# Where to download MITK Workbench plugins

Tags: plugins, download, mitk

I'm new to MITK Workbench and I can't seem to find where to download plugins. Specifically, I'm looking for a link to download the Registration plugin so that I can align two images with the deformable image registration method. Any direction to a link would be greatly appreciated.

-KBS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently MITK does not allow to download Plugins for Extentions, you would have to build it from source and activate them in Cmake.
However, the Registration Plugin is included into the latest Release 2016.11 (its the MatchPoint Plugin).

Answer (score 0):

As chriswe wrote, MITK doesn't work by downloading plugin. You simply need to download the MITK Workbench [from their website](http://mitk.org/wiki/Downloads) and it will already contain all the plugins MITK created.

If you want to know how to code a new plugin, that's a totally different question! By the way, the MITK Mailing List is really active so it's a good place to ask questions.